# Console app parallel Tasks don't keep the processor busy

Tags: c#, multithreading, performance, parallel-processing, console

I have a C# console program written with .NET 6.   I first wrote the code so that it ran sequentially in one thread.   It works.    If I look at the task manager, one of my 16 logical processors is very busy and the rest all doing basically nothing.   Which is exactly what I expect.  The subroutine (ok, it's really a static void method) that does the real work runs thousands of times.  I changed the code so that in a loop it queues up the tasks and adds it to a list:

```
Task t = Task.Run(() => SeekAnswer(param));
tasks.Add(t);
```

After the loop of queuing is done, we wait until all the parallel threads are done:

```
Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
```

The code works and gives  the same answers as the sequential code.   Yay.    But it was only like 30% faster than the sequential code.  I was expecting like a factor of 5 or even 10 speedup.  If I look at the task manager, I see that each logical processor is loafing along at around 20% and there's no longer one logical processor that's 100% busy.    Because the analysis task, `SeekAnswer`, is only CPU bound, i expected each logical processor would be at 100% and the machine would overall start to feel sluggish.  `SeekAnswer` does no I/O, no disk activity, no networking, no yields or awaits or anything like that.  `SeekAnswer` takes about 500 ms to run and when it's done, it adds its results to a list.

One guess is that because it's a console app, the console part is stealing cycles where it's waiting to see if there's mouse movement or keyboard inputs or something.  If I go into the task manager and set its priority to Real Time, maybe each processor goes from 20% to 23%.  Another guess is that the C# task manager/CLR can't fully load down intel hyperthreading logical processors.

My question is what is preventing me from more fully utilizing the processors?

Comment: Is there one concurrent List that is shared between the Tasks, or does each task have it's own list? There might be a bottleneck there.

Comment: yes, when SeekAnswer has an answer, it adds to a common list.   I added a stop watch before and after that List Add and it appeared not to take anytime.  If it was running full out, it would have to run that List Add 30 times a second which doesn't sound like there should be much contention.

Comment: The answer being added to to the answer list is pretty small, maybe 4 or 5 short strings and a few integers.

Comment: Can you try giving each Task it's own "storage", just for comparison?

Comment: Yes, @jeanluc162 , that's a great suggestion.   Just for fun, I'll just comment out where it adds the answer to the list and see how it behaves.

Comment: I would suggest to switch your example from using `Task`s to using `Thread`s. Currently you are talking about threads and your are presenting code that uses tasks, so everyone will be inclined to inform you that `threads != tasks`. Which is true but also not helpful for solving your problem. My guess is that your core problem is RAM-related. Maybe the CPU requests access to RAM so frequently and erratically, that the RAM bandwidth is saturated.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias You are right that I don't understand the differences between threads and tasks.   I will have to research.   Tasks, which i am using, seems appropriate at first glance.

Comment: @jeanluc162 I commented out the List Add Answer and the overall processor utilization maybe went up a few percent, so there is some contention to add answers to a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current solution splits the work into N tasks. In general, you should prefer higher-level abstractions. `Parallel` or PLINQ can probably partition your work into tasks more effectively than your current "one call per task" solution.

> when SeekAnswer has an answer, it adds to a common list.

Remove all coordination. If you're collecting results, then just *return* the results and use something like PLINQ to collect them.

> One guess is that because it's a console app, the console part is stealing cycles where it's waiting to see if there's mouse movement or keyboard inputs or something.

No, it won't do that. It listens to signals but there's no polling going on. And even if it *was* polling, that would show up as CPU usage.

> If I go into the task manager and set its priority to Real Time, maybe each processor goes from 20% to 23%.

CPU-bound tasks - rather counterintuitively - should run at a *lower* priority. The NT scheduling system that underlies all modern Windows OSes will automatically adjust this priority for you.

> Another guess is that the C# thread manager/CLR can't fully load down intel hyperthreading logical processors.

Not a limitation of the CLR.

It's important to understand how hyperthreading actually works: there's only **one core** that can execute code instructions. Hyperthreaded processors work by duplicating the instruction pipelines, and that's it. Each core still only runs one instruction at a time. The benefit of hyperthreading comes when an instruction has to do something like a memory read and would normally stall the processor; in that case the hyperthreading can switch to a different logical processor and continue its instruction pipeline instead.

TL;DR: If your work doesn't ever stall (i.e., it fits into the CPU cache), hyperthreading can't provide any speedups. This is true regardless of language/runtime/OS.

---

It's possible you *might* be waiting for some thread injection. For a console application, the [minimum threads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool.setminthreads?view=net-6.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5000058) *should* be set to the processor count, but those threads are used for some housekeeping tasks. You can experiment with setting the minimum (worker) thread count higher.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer.   I will have to try setting the minimum threads.

Comment: Maybe the work doesn't stall, and so the hyperthreading isn't providing any use and thus the maximum utilization as seen in the Task Manager is 50% of the logical cores (100% of the physical cores).

Comment: I tried setting the minimum threads to 16, 20, and 32.   I think it did best at 20 but nothing dramatically better.

Comment: @Knox: To get a complete answer, we'd need a problem we can reproduce.

Comment: I tried the program on several other computers.  On an i5-8259   with 4 cores/8 logical, the program behaved as I expected:  it was at 100% utilization.   On another i7, it behaved more like on my dev machine.   Other machines were somewhere in between.   
I think it may have to do with the way that Windows uses the hyperthreading and processor caches.   I would have to look more at PLINQ if I decide to continue trying to improve its utilization on i7's.