# Can't fully utilize my CPU when using async Task in C#

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task

I can't get my CPU to 100% using Async method in C#, my average is around 50%. I am unsure if there is a lock, garbage collection, or other behind-the-scene tasks that are slowing my App.
The task and its results are pure calculations, there are no I/O or network requests.
Does my code need any enhancements?

[image]

```
            for (int i = 0; i < loops; i++)
            {
                List<Task<List<Distance>>> DistanceTask = new List<Task<List<Distance>>>();
                foreach (var item in dstpart)
                {
                    List<string> itemKeywords = item.Keywords.Split(',').Take(10).ToList();
                    DistanceTask.Add(Task.Run(() => CalculateDistances(itemKeywords))); 
                    //one task takes around 5sec to complete, no IO or network requests
                }
                var results = await Task.WhenAll(DistanceTask);
                foreach (var r in results)
                {
                    //evaluate the results, no IO or network operations here, It's few (ms)
                }
            }
```

Comment: Can you post complete code?

Comment: Recent similar question: [Console app parallel Tasks don't keep the processor busy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73988349/console-app-parallel-tasks-dont-keep-the-processor-busy).

Comment: You seem to have Hyper-Threading (physical cores split into two logical cores each). If you are actually fully utilizing them, one logical core will use up the entire physical core, leaving the other unused, ie ~50% total CPU usage if you count by core. The results seem correct.

Comment: You are correct, I was just testing on another I9 CPU, and the utilization was near 100%..

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with the pattern.  This simplification pegs all my CPUs

```
var loops = 100;
var dstpart = Enumerable.Range(1, 100).ToList();
for (int i = 0; i < loops; i++)
{
    List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
    foreach (var item in dstpart)
    {
        
        tasks.Add(Task.Run(() =>Spin() ));
        //one task takes around 5sec to complete, no IO or network requests
    }
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
  
}

void Spin()
{
    var sw = new Stopwatch();

    sw.Start();
    while (sw.ElapsedMilliseconds < 5000)
        Thread.SpinWait(10000);
}
```

Comment: It turns out to be my CPU issue, the code runs @ 100% on I9 CPU I just tested.